# aws s3 private yum repository error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yum

I am trying to use [yum-s3-plugin](https://github.com/jbraeuer/yum-s3-plugin) plugin to create private yum repository on aws s3 bucket called s3-rpm-repo. I have a dedicated user with the following policy:

```
    {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1417601934000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketAcl",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
        "s3:GetBucketTagging",
        "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl",
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::s3-rpm-repo"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1417602286000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1417602331000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::s3-rpm-repo/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have installed plugin and python-boto. Following is yum repository setup:

```
[ss-s3-rpm-repo]
name=ss-s3-rpm-repo
baseurl=http://s3-rpm-repo.s3.amazonaws.com/amzn/$basearch
gpgcheck=0
priority=1
s3_enabled=1
debuglevel=10
logfile=/tmp/yum.log
key_id=AKIA...7WTQ
secret_key=X65...F
```

But when I try to update repository I am getting error:

```
[root@s3yum tmp]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, s3, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos-mirror.jchost.net
 * extras: mirror.thelinuxfix.com
 * updates: mirror.vcu.edu
ss-s3-rpm-repo - amzn/x86_64/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in <module>
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 285, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 136, in main
    result, resultmsgs = base.doCommands()
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 434, in doCommands
    self._getTs(needTsRemove)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/depsolve.py", line 99, in _getTs
    self._getTsInfo(remove_only)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/depsolve.py", line 110, in _getTsInfo
    pkgSack = self.pkgSack
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 887, in <lambda>
    pkgSack = property(fget=lambda self: self._getSacks(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 669, in _getSacks
    self.repos.populateSack(which=repos)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/repos.py", line 308, in populateSack
    sack.populate(repo, mdtype, callback, cacheonly)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 165, in populate
    if self._check_db_version(repo, mydbtype):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 223, in _check_db_version
    return repo._check_db_version(mdtype)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 1256, in _check_db_version
    repoXML = self.repoXML
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 1455, in <lambda>
    repoXML = property(fget=lambda self: self._getRepoXML(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 1447, in _getRepoXML
    self._loadRepoXML(text=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 1437, in _loadRepoXML
    return self._groupLoadRepoXML(text, self._mdpolicy2mdtypes())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 1412, in _groupLoadRepoXML
    if self._commonLoadRepoXML(text):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 1230, in _commonLoadRepoXML
    result = self._getFileRepoXML(local, text)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 1008, in _getFileRepoXML
    size=102400) # setting max size as 100K
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 830, in _getFile
    size=size
  File "/usr/lib/yum-plugins/s3.py", line 173, in urlgrab
    key = self._key(key_name)
  File "/usr/lib/yum-plugins/s3.py", line 165, in _key
    return bucket.get_key(key_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 192, in get_key
    key, resp = self._get_key_internal(key_name, headers, query_args_l)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 234, in _get_key_internal
    response.status, response.reason, '')
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
```

Does anybody experienced the same or similar error before?
Thanks for any hints.